# Called the same javascript array function and behaving is different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to write 2 actions for React app.

```
export const changeFilter = (newFilter) => {

return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER});
    axios.get( 'http://localhost:8762/event/events?') // + eventsSelector.getEventsFilter()
        .then( response => {
            dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER_SUCCESS,payload:response});
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER_FAIL,error:error});
        } );


  }
};
```

and

```
export const getEventsByFilter = () => {

return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER});
    axios.get( 'http://localhost:8762/event/events?') // + eventsSelector.getEventsFilter()
        .then( response => {
            dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER_SUCCESS,payload:response});
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            dispatch({type:types.GET_EVENTS_BY_FILTER_FAIL,error:error});
        } );
    }
};
```

When I hit on return(dispatch) line in getEventsByFilter and press F10 to debug(in Chrome developer tools), I go to next line(which is expected behavior). Unfortunately, when I try to call changeFilter method and hit line return(dispatch) and hit F10 to go to next line debugger lead me to closed bracket of return statement instead on next line. I also checked log because I have redux logger installed and actions are dispatched just for getEventsByFilter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called these methods differently. Both of them were declared in eventActions file and I had this in component that called this functions:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getEvents: () => dispatch(eventActions.getEvents()),
        getEventsByFilter: () => dispatch(eventActions.getEventsByFilter()),
        changeFilter: (newFilter) => dispatch(eventActions.changeFilter(newFilter))
    }
};
```

For getEventsByFilter I used `this.props.getEventsByFilter();` and `changeFilter` was called like this `eventActions.changeFilter({priceFrom:event.target.value});`. I missed `dispatch` for `changeFilter` method.